# Mule application url - MMC

Tags: mule, mmc

I have installed the trail MMC. depolyed 2 application there. 1 using mule console and second using Cloudhub(target- configured mmc server there).

## what would be the url for both.

1. tomcat is running on port :8585
2. serverName: himserver-onpromice
3. applicationName deployed using mmc console: findName
4. applicationName deployed using clouhub console: getMyName

I checked with below but not working,..
http://himserver-onpromice:8585/getMyName/

Answer (score 0):

MMC is on-premise deployment and hence it will use the ports configured inside your mule application. If we assume you are using HTTP listener connector as input source then you should use the configured port for it. The default port is 8081 (on cloud default port is 80). Hence, in this case URL should be: http://himserver-onpromice:8081/findName/getMyName/

Comment: Thanks for reply vijay. i checked same but not working.. error is himserver-onpromice’s server DNS address could not be found.
i see that application is in running status on cloud

Comment: findName and getMyName is two saparate application, which has been deployed different ways

Comment: The server name provided is on cloud or local? May be I miss-interpreted question. Do you want to access both applications from cloud? Your one application should act as proxy on cloud for the other (on premise).